# Changing the icon of an exe resulted from building in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, windows, icons, codeblocks

I made a little program in C (the content doesn't matter) and built it in CodeBlocks (GNU GCC Compiler), thus resulting in an executable file. I want to change the icon of said .exe file but so far I didnt succeed.

I tried Resource Hacker however the 'change icon option' seems unavailable. Also I dont want to change the icon of a shortcut of the .exe, but having the .exe keep its icon if i send it to someone. Any tips?

Comment: In Windows you make a `.RC` resource file and compile and link it with the executable.

Comment: You specify your icon in your `.rc` file. You compile your `.rc` file to an object file using `windres youfile.rc yourfile.obj` and then just link the object file as any other normal object file when compiling your final executable.